# Pandas scan directories and take new Excel files into Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to scan the Excel files in Python that have the same name in two different folders and add the most recent of these files to my Dataframe. How can I do that, can you help in this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a for loop to iterate through the files and choose the one with the most recent "last modified" date, which can be accessed through the os module.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

filelist = ['your/path/tofile1', 'your/path/tofile2', 'your/path/tofile3']
filedate = 0
for file in filelist:
    if os.path.getmtime(file) > filedate: 
        newestfile, filedate = file, os.path.getmtime(file)
df = pd.read_excel(newestfile)
```